# could not parse ssh: [default]: stat /tmp/ssh-qpL02JZP5k7x/agent.28198: no such file or directory

Tags: docker, sockets, ssh, docker-buildkit

AFAIK the error means that there is no file named `agent.28198` in the mentioned directory, but upon listing its contents the file (local socket file) is clearly there. What could be the reason for docker's inability to get the socket?

Here is the full command scenario:

```
$ eval $(ssh-agent -s)
Agent pid 28199
$ ssh-add
Enter passphrase for /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa: 
Identity added: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa)
$ DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --ssh default -t my_image .
could not parse ssh: [default]: stat /tmp/ssh-qpL02JZP5k7x/agent.28198: no such file or directory
$ ls -l /tmp/ssh-qpL02JZP5k7x/
total 0
srw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 Sep  9 08:50 agent.28198
```

Answer (score 1):

Docker is installed from snap - that's the culprit. It does not have access to `/tmp` folder because of that. To remediate, remove the package from snap - `sudo snap remove docker` and install it via `dpkg` ([link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#install-from-a-package)).